# Undefined Column in Class does not exist?

Tags: python, flask

I receiving the error `(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "time_stamp" of relation "geotag" does not exist`. In my `Class Geotag(db.model)` I have this column for timestamp inside the Geotag class `time_stamp = db.column(db.DateTime())`. Where I think the problem is coming from is that in routes I have this function below that is in my routes.py.  I am trying to timestamp the form along with the two other attributes. However it keeps giving me this error that my time_stamp in the class does not exist

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
            # generate geotag
            geotag = Geotag(
                serial_number = form.label.data,
                coord = f'POINT({form.longitude.data} {form.latitude.data})',
                time_stamp = datetime.now()
            
            )
```

EDIT:

**Models.py:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from geoalchemy2 import Geography

class Geotag(db.Model):
    # barcode
    serial_number = db.Column(db.String(15), primary_key=True)
    coord         = db.Column(Geography(geometry_type='POINT', srid=4326), index=True)

    #Time Stamp
    time_stamp    = db.Column(db.DateTime())

    # longitude and latitude.
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.coord:
            return f'<Geotag {self.serial_number} {type(self.coord)} {self.coord.desc}>'
        else:
            return f'<Geotag {self.serial_number}>'
```

**routes.py:**

```
@app.route('/api/geotag', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def geotag_endpoint():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        from flask import escape
        q = db.session.query(Geotag.serial_number, functions.ST_AsText(Geotag.coord),Geotag.time_stamp).all() #add Geotag.time_stamp in here functions.ST_AsText(Geotag.time_stamp)
        return escape("\n".join([f'{serial_number} {coords} {time_stamp} ' for serial_number,coords,time_stamp in q]))
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = GPSForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            # generate geotag
            geotag = Geotag(
                serial_number = form.label.data,
                coord = f'POINT({form.longitude.data} {form.latitude.data})',
                time_stamp = datetime.now()
            
            )
```

**Javascript code snippet for timestamp submission**

```
<form id="gps-form" action="{{ api_endpoint }}" method="POST" onsubmit = "capture_Timestamp()"> 
...
{%block script %}
<script>
    function capture_Timestamp(){
        document.getElementById('DateTime').value = Date.now();

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show your full models and view??

Comment: @Aditya I have posted an edited version. Please take a look at it! Thank you

Comment: Sorry I must asked it before but can you post the full error/ traceback as it's really difficult to tell where's the error in the code